# How do I create a custom PromptDialog member function?

Tags: c#, botframework

I tried making a custom class with the following member function

```
{[Serializable]
public class CustomPromptDialog : PromptDialog
{
    public static void Text(IDialogContext context, ResumeAfter<string> resume, IMessageActivity prompt)
    {
        context.PostAsync(prompt);
    }
}}
```

I did this because I wanted prompt to show user an option of quick replies for Facebook. I could not do this using `PromptDialog.Text(context, Query, prompt);` as this method only accepts a prompt of type sting

Comment: What happened? Did you solve your issue ?

Comment: Thanx @BobSwager. That won't work in my case. I wouldn't want to use PromptDialog.Choice as it would limit the amount of responses users can send. I instead wanted to use PromptChoice.Text because that would allow users to type anything and provide quick replies as an option but PromptChoice.Text accepts a prompt of type string which I cannot convert to IMessageActivity if I want to offer quick replies. I have tried this however 'PromptDialog.Text(context, Search, prompt); context.PostAsync(reply);' with reply showing quick replies but sometimes the quick replies are overlapped by PromptDialog

Comment: That's might be another problem or Facebook bug maybe ?

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to make a plan around that

Comment: Did you solve your issue ?

Comment: Yes thanks @BobSwager. I instead created quick replies and a context.Wait() method with a Resume after Task that accepts a text input

Comment: Please mark my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override your prompt style. Check [this](http://southworks.com/blog/2016/09/21/using-facebooks-quickreplies-with-promptdialogs/) .